# yarn workspace not update the local package (making eslint plugin)

Tags: eslint, yarn-workspaces

## Problem

I'm making custom eslint plugin referencing [working with plugins](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/working-with-plugins) and [generator-eslint](https://github.com/eslint/generator-eslint). Then I make a monorepo using yarn workspace and turbo repo like following structure:

### file structure

```
apps
  service
    .eslintrc.js
    index.ts (written to throw eslint error)
    package.json
packages
  eslint-plugin-custom
    lib
      rules
        func-prefix-matching.js
      index.js
    .eslintrc.js
    package.json
package.json
turbo.json
```

The key files of it is:

#### apps/service/.eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['eslint:recommended'],
  plugins: ['eslint-plugin-custom'],
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  rules: {
    "custom/func-prefix-matching": ['error']
  }
};
```

#### apps/service/package.json

```json
{
  "name": "service",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-custom": "*",
    "typescript": "^4.5.3"
  }
}
```

#### packages/eslint-plugin-custom/lib/rules/func-prefix-matching.js

```js
"use strict";

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Rule Definition
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const rulePrefix = ["is", "pre", "on", "post", "get", "set"];
const isValidName = (name, { prefix, exclude }) => {
  const isValid = (prefix) => name.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
  return exclude.some(isValid) || prefix.some(isValid);
};

/** @type {import('eslint').Rule.RuleModule} */
module.exports = {
  meta: {
    type: 'suggestion', // `problem`, `suggestion`, or `layout`
    docs: {
      description: 'exmaple',
      recommended: false,
      url: null, // URL to the documentation page for this rule
    },
    fixable: null, // Or `code` or `whitespace`
    schema: [], // Add a schema if the rule has options
    messages: {
      example: 'example',
    },
  },

  create(context) {
    const { options } = context;
    const {include = [], exclude = [] } = options[0]||{};

    return {
      Identifier: (node) => {
        if (node.parent.init && node.parent.init.type === 'ArrowFunctionExpression'
          // You can add more checks here
        ) {
          const { name } = node;
          const allPrefix = [...include, ...rulePrefix].sort();
          // Sorting is optional

          if (!isValidName(name, { prefix: allPrefix, exclude })) {
            context.report({
              node,
              messageId: `${name} should start with ${allPrefix.join(", ")}.`,
            });
          }
        }
      },
    };
  },
};
```

#### packages/eslint-plugin-custom/package.json

```json
{
  "name": "eslint-plugin-custom",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ESLint plugin",
  "keywords": [
    "eslint",
    "eslintplugin",
    "eslint-plugin"
  ],
  "author": "inflab",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "exports": "./lib/index.js",
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "mocha tests --recursive --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "requireindex": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^14.17.0 || ^16.0.0 || >= 18.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "eslint": ">=7"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "custom-lint",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "turbo run build",
    "dev": "turbo run dev --parallel",
    "lint": "turbo run lint",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md}\"",
    "test": "turbo run test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "latest",
    "turbo": "latest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19"
}
```

#### turbo.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {},
    "lint": {
      "outputs": []
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false
    },
    "test": {}
  }
}
```

### issue

Now, eslint make output:

```
[Error - 10:34:20 PM] TypeError: context.report() called with a messageId of 'function1 should start with get, is, on, post, pre, set.' which is not present in the 'messages' config: {
  "example": "example"
}
Occurred while linting /custom-lint/apps/service/index.ts:1
```

So I edit code like:

```js
"use strict";

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Rule Definition
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const rulePrefix = ["is", "pre", "on", "post", "get", "set"];
const isValidName = (name, { prefix, exclude }) => {
  const isValid = (prefix) => name.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
  return exclude.some(isValid) || prefix.some(isValid);
};

/** @type {import('eslint').Rule.RuleModule} */
module.exports = {
  meta: {
    ...
    messages: {
      messageId: 'message',
    },
  },

  create(context) {
    ...

    return {
      Identifier: (node) => {
        if (node.parent.init && node.parent.init.type === 'ArrowFunctionExpression'
          // You can add more checks here
        ) {
          const { name } = node;
          const allPrefix = [...include, ...rulePrefix].sort();
          // Sorting is optional

          if (!isValidName(name, { prefix: allPrefix, exclude })) {
            context.report({
              node,
              messageId: 'messageId',
            });
          }
        }
      },
    };
  },
};
```

Then yarn workspace automatically make symlink to the `eslint-plugin-custom` package and I can see the latest edited code in `(project root)/node_modules/eslint-plugin-custom`. But the same error is occurred.

```
[Error - 10:34:20 PM] TypeError: context.report() called with a messageId of 'function1 should start with get, is, on, post, pre, set.' which is not present in the 'messages' config: {
  "example": "example"
}
Occurred while linting /custom-lint/apps/service/index.ts:1
```

### what I tried

- It looks like cache problem, so I run `yarn cache clean`. But not work
- I change the plugin version like

#### packages/eslint-plugin-custom/package.json

```json
{
  "name": "eslint-plugin-custom",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  ...
}
```

#### apps/service/package.json

```json
{
  "name": "service",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-custom": "1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.3"
  }
}
```

to match exact version, but it does not work.

- removing `node_modules` dirs and re-install, not work.

## what I expect

I expect

- the plugin work correctly
- to see the output of eslint change when I edit plugin code

Is there any help... :(